# Can't fill my collection views with API data by using Alamofire

Tags: swift, api, url, uicollectionview, alamofire

There is an api (https://docs.api.jikan.moe/#section/Information). I get data from it, but I can’t display them in my collection views in any way. The data should come, I checked. I implement filling the collection view cells through the view model [ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BhTT.png) <-> [ViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAKGR.png) and with Network Manager [API Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHHzV.png)

The result is just white collectionView - [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrvEg.jpg)

For the first time I decided to work with Alamofire and apparently I don’t understand something. Please tell me what is the problem. Link to [github](https://github.com/Shalai-Ivan/Anime-Store) in case someone needs it.

> Updated

The problem might be with asynchronous coding. And i still have no ideas to fix it, cause don't understand the GCD as well.  [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxodO.png)

```
func fetchRequest(typeRequest: TypeRequest) -> [AnimeModel] {
var animeModels: [AnimeModel] = []
switch typeRequest {
case .name(let name):
    let urlString = "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?q=\(name)"
    AF.request(urlString).response { response in
        guard let data = response.data else { return print("NO DATA FOR - \(name)") }
        do {
            let json = try JSON(data: data)
            let title = json["data"][0]["title_english"].string ?? "Anime"
            let imageURL = json["data"][0]["images"]["jpg"]["image_url"].string ?? ""
            let image = AnimeModel.downloadImage(stringURL: imageURL)
            animeModels.append(AnimeModel(image: image, title: title))
            print(".NAME ANIME MODELS - \(animeModels)")
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
print("BEFORE RETURN ANIME MODELS - \(animeModels)")
return animeModels    // returns empty array and then "animeModel.append()" is applied
```

}

Comment: It's unclear. I checked your project: You have 4 `UICollectionView`, which one causes the issue? Also, I saw only one `reloadData()`, but only for one collection, and I don't see where is calling that method `updateInterface(animeModel:)` Because currently, you `fetchModel()`, but never "listen" to when you receive the content?

Comment: I saw the issue. In `fetchRequest(typeRequest:), add a print just before `return animeModels`, and one when you do `animeModels.append(...)`, let's write "print("Inside Alamofire closure") & print("Before return"), which one is printed first in console? Which one did you expect to be printed first? You are missing the asynchrone concept. Look for "Swift + Closure + Async", or maybe for await/async...

Comment: @Larme Yeah, you are right. This method returns an empty array before it had been filled. I updated my question, cause i am still trying to solve it.